# Will my Verizon FiOS router be a bottleneck if used just as a bridge?

Tags: wireless-router, bridge-router, fios

My family has an Actiontec MI424WR-Rev. D router given to us by Verizon when we upgraded to FiOS back in 2008. As can be expected from period technology, its top speed (on a good day) is a whopping 54 megabits/second. We're thinking of getting [a better router](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0098QV038) and connecting it to FiOS with [the steps detailed here](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-Your-Own-Router-With-Verizon-FiOS). My question: Will the Actiontec's pathetic speeds bottleneck the new router's performance? And if so, is there any way to use a new router on FiOS without such a bottleneck?

Comment: 54mbits is the max theoretical wireless speed. Presumably it has a 100mbit ethernet lan port. So no matter what wireless speed you attain with a new wireless device attached to the Actiontec 100mbit ethernet port, your max theoretical speed **to the internet** is going to be 100mbit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 424 rev.D can do 100 megabits on wired connections (both cat5 and coax).

Since you've been on FiOS so many years, see if your local Verizon will replace your router with a newer version. (Start the conversation nice, but if needed talk about switching to cable). I think the latest is rev.I, which offers gigabit LAN, 270 megabit WAN.